# Why is my Bevel modifier not working on my object after using Boolean?

Tags: bevel, object-mode

I want to bevel the edges of my object, but my Bevel modifier is not making any changes when I change the values. I did already use two Booleans, so I feel like the issue might be caused by the mesh.
Scale is fine. Recalculated normals, but nothing.

Here is the file: [image]

[image]

Comment: Turn off Clamp Overlap on the Geometry dropdown on the Bevel modifier. You'll then need to turn down the Amount to 0.01 to prevent overlaps.

Comment: I prefer not to do that, because Clamp Overlay gives a messy result

Comment: It's fine if you turn down the Amount as I added to my previous comment. - The Amount is usually set far to high by default anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to turn off *Clamp Overlap*, you can change the *Limit Method* to *Vertex Group* instead.

Comment: John Eason is right, your bevel "doesn't work" because it's limited to roughly 0, because the overlap starts almost immediately. You can't eat a cookie and have a cookie, either you have an overlap, or you have no bevel. Of curse you can be smart about it and either influence how bevel creates the geometry, or you can manually improve the topology after bevel, or as Stef suggests, you could limit the bevel to some selection, where the topology generated by bevel gives you some space before overlap happens.

Comment: The question is why does the Clamp Overlap stop the bevel, because I can't put my finger on the faces overlapping...